# Can I set a different "default" browser for each workspace on Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon, browser, workspaces

I am running Arch Linux with Cinnamon as my desktop environment. I have set up a few workspaces, and use workspace 1 for work and workspace 2 for non-work stuff. I use Chromium as my work web browser and Brave as my non-work browser. What I would like to achieve is when I click on a URL in any application currently displayed in workspace1, that will be opened in chromium and if I click on a link in an application from workspace2, that should open in Brave.

For example, a friend sends me a telegram message, and my telegram app is on my non-work workspace. I already have an open Brave window in that workspace, but because my default browser is set to Chromium, when I click on the telegram link, that will open in the existing Chromium window of my work workspace instead of in the existing Brave window of my non-work workspace

So, essentially, I want a different default browser per desktop/workspace. Is this possible? I can't find any such setting, but maybe there's something in dconf?

Comment: Good question. I don't think so, you could script something, and set the default from a script whenever the workspace changes. However, for that purpose, I'd go with a completely different user and switch via "Ctrl+Alt+Fn".

Comment: No, I do not think it is possible with a standard config. But I would suggest to start by making you own launcher - put it as a default browser, and the launcher will decide which actual browser to start depending on workspace. No idea right now how to write it, but it should be possible.

Comment: @WhiteOwl the problem is that I already have the browsers open, it isn't about launching a new one, but about where the page should open. For example, a friend sends me a telegram message, and my telegram app is on my non-work workspace. I already have an open Brave window in that workspace, but because my default browser is set to chromium, when I click on the telegram link, that will open in the existing chromium window of my work workspace instead of in the existing brave window of my non-work workspace.

Comment: @pLumo yeah, that's what I want to avoid. That would be more cumbersome than simply copying the URL and pasting into the desired browser instead of just clicking on it.

Comment: In the vein of what @WhiteOwl mentioned, you should be able to get the current workspace using something like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/900970/how-do-i-look-up-the-name-of-the-current-workspace

Then use the current workspace value in your wrapper script, and then set your wrapper as the default browser (not sure how to do the last bit in Cinnamon as I've never used it).

Comment: do you switch workspaces with keyboard shortcuts only? (probably not?) Then you might be able to use something like xbindkeys to use that keyboaard shortcut to run a script that would set some env variables that control the default browser?

Comment: I do most things with keyboard shortcuts, actually, including switching workspaces, yes. But why would that be relevant? And what env variables?

Comment: @éclairevoyant hmm. That might work, thanks. I'll see if I can figure it out.